# Is restriction a closed map?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, gn.general-topology, topological-vector-spaces

Originally [asked](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2831043/is-restriction-a-closed-map) on MSE.

Let $X$ be a normal (or even metrizable) topological space and let $Y$ be a closed subset of $X$. Let $C(X)$ be the linear space of all continuous scalar functions on $X$ endowed with the compact-open topology. Consider a map $R:C(X)\to C(Y)$ defined by $Rf=f|_Y$. This map is obviously linear, and it is easy to see that it is continuous. By Tietze theorem it is also surjective. It seems that this is in fact a quotient map. However, what interests me is the following question:

> Let $B$ be a closed convex balanced subset of $C(X)$. Is $RB$ closed in $C(Y)$?

Under additional assumption that $B$ is weakly compact, this is true, since then $B$ is compact in the pointwise topology, and so $RB$ is pointwise compact, and so pointwise closed, and so closed in $C(Y)$. I can also show that this is wrong if we don't require $Y$ to be closed in $X$.

Comment: many  years ago I  read  a  theorem in a  paper  that there is  linear  isometric  embedding  from $C(Y)$ to $C(X)$ which act  by  extension. that is: there  is  an isometric  section for  the  map you  consider. I really  do not  not remember that paper because I read it  more than 10 years ago. but this  obviously implies that  the restriction map is closed.

Comment: may  be  Michael  selection lemma is  helpful to construct  an  appropriate  right inverse(section)/

Comment: @AliTaghavi do I understand you correctly that there is an isometry $S$ from $C(Y)$ into $C(X)$ such that $RS=Id$? I guess that $X$ is assumed to be compact in this statement. I don't see immediately why this implies that $R$ is a closed map..

Comment: I am sorry I was mistaken. my comment was inappropriate.

Comment: If $X$ is metrizable, then the Dugundji Extension Theorem (1951) yields a linear continuous extension operator $C(Y)\to C(X)$, which implies that $C(Y)$ is complemented in $C(X)$. This (classical) result of Dugudji was later generalized to stratifiable spaces by Borges, see Theorem 5.23 in the survey paper "Generalized metric spaces" of Gruenhage in the "Handbook of Set-Theoretic Topology".

Comment: @AliTaghavi: selection theorems do give a right inverse to any bounded linear surjective operator between Banach spaces, which is however  in general not linear (thus also nowhere differentiable). In the present case, the extension is a bounded linear operator by construction.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer to the main question is negative:

Consider the compact subset $X=[0,1]\cup \{2\}$ of the real line and let $Y=\{2\}$ be a singleton in $X$. In the function space $C(X)$ consider the closed convex balanced subset
$$B:=\{f\in C(X):\sup_{x\in [0,1]}|f(x)|\le 1,\;f(0)=0,\;f(2)=\int_0^1 f(t)dt\}.$$ It is easy to see that for the restriction operator $R:C(X)\to C(Y)$, the image  $R(B)=\{f\in C(Y):|f(2)|<1\}$ is not closed in $C(Y)$.